# Change Names in Source Qualifier Updates Column Names in Existing Transformations Located in Mapping

Tags: mapping, informatica

When I change the column names in the Source Qualifier or a joiner transformation, the names are not updated in my existing transformations such as filters and expressions that are in my mapping. Is there a way to change the column names and have the existing transformations in the mapping automatically update with the new name.

I had created a mapping.  I then tried to change the column name in Source Qualifier but this does not update the column names in the existing transformations.

I am hoping that when I change the column names in the Source Qualifier that existing transformations with this column name is updated as well.

[Name of Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v42g2.png)

Answer (score 0):

You change the Source Qualifier and name the ports as to your liking.

Now you select and mark all those "NAME*" ports, right-click on them, and choose Propagate; in the following screen mask you check the Name radio button and click Propagate, and all these port names are forwarded as far as possible to connected downstream transformations.